# SSIS regex issue in find replace

Tags: regex, ssis

Coming from a Unix background in the 80s, I've grown to rely on regular expressions to write code. Frequently, I perform tasks such as taking a list and inserting quotes and commas. in SSIS, when I match to the end of a line using either \n or $, the insert is always place after the line. eg-

```
one
two
three
```

find: $

replace: ',

results in:

```
one
',
two
',
three
',
```

Why does this not work as expected? is there a workaround?

Comment: What is not working as expected ? Can you be a little more clear ?

Comment: @David: This seems to be specific to SSIS (a service I am not familiar with). Does finding `\n` instead of `$` give the same result ? If this is the case, you could try matching the whole line and capturing it, then replace it by the same thing followed by `',` (regex : `^(.*)$` replace with `\1',`)

Comment: found workaround- use \r instead of $